# How to access this.$refs in <script setup> Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper/issues/371#issuecomment-404471659), only with `<script setup>` tag which doesn't have `this` keyword.

**Template (from code that I'm trying to replicate)**

```
<swiper ref="swiper">
    <swiper-slide></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide></swiper-slide>
</swiper>

<a class="swiper-navigation is-previous" @click="swiper.slidePrev()"></a>
<a class="swiper-navigation is-next" @click="swiper.slideNext()"></a>
```

**Script (from code that I'm trying to replicate)**

```
computed: {
    swiper() {
        return this.$refs.swiper.swiper;
    }
}
```

Tried to use `getCurrentInstance()` but for some reason `getCurrentInstance().refs` return empty object `{}` even though it's there when I do `console.log(getCurrentInstance())`.

**My `<script setup>` component**

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

const swiper = // ???

const handleNextSlide = () => swiper.slideNext()
const handlePrevSlide = () => swiper.slidePrev()

</script>


<template>

<div>

    <button @click="handlePrevSlide()">Prev</button>
    <button @click="handleNextSlide()">Next</button>

    <Swiper ref="swiper">
        <SwiperSlide>1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>5</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>

</div>

</template>
```

Comment: Can you share de complete vue component?

Comment: `script setup` does not use syntax like `computed: { swiper() {}}`. How are you using that? You need to share more code.

Comment: @cSharp The first two code blocks are from code that I'm trying to replicate. I also added the third block with what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the equivalent to:

```js
computed: {
    swiper() {
        return this.$refs.swiper.swiper;
    }
}
```

in `script setup`, you just need to:

```html
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
...

const swiper  = ref(null)

// .swiper will only work if the ref swiper (Swiper element) has a property named swiper
const swiperComputed = computed(() => swiper.value.swiper)

...
</script>

<template>
  <Swiper ref="swiper">
    <SwiperSlide>1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>3</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>4</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>5</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
</template>
```

Comment: how to get correct typing when doing `ref(null)` for some HTML element?

Comment: you could either be very generic by writing `ref(null as HTMLElement | null)` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) or you be more specific and declare the expected type, e.g. `ref(null as HTMLCanvasElement | null)` (here is a full list: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the vue docs on template refs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs

Make sure to set the API reference to "composition api":

[image]

You want:
`const swiper = ref(null)`;

At least that is my assumption based on your code. If this swiper tool is compatible with vue 3 then in theory that should work.

Since this is a ref, you need to use `.value` to access it, so you'd want:
`const handleNextSlide = () => swiper.value.slideNext()`

Finally, since you are using typescript, you can do something like
`const swiper = ref<Swiper | null>(null)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `refs` in `Options API`, you need to wait `mounted() hooks`.

**Note that you can only access the ref after the component is mounted.**

**Edit:** Or `onMounted(() => {})` hook

Documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs